# WPF Canvas, Framework element has red border

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, drawingvisual

I'm using a canvas to host various framework elements. Each framework element is itself a host to a DrawingVisual.

Each Framework element that is added at design time, appears fine (i.e. as expected) in the canvas at runtime.

For those framework elements added at runtime (canvas.children.add(new myframework...), they all have a red border. I stress the fact that I am definitely NOT drawing this border - I've even removed all drawing instructions and still a red border frames each control. If I reintroduce the drawing instructions, this red border appears OVER my drawing, so it appears to be something WPF is doing.

There is no XAML involved - it's simply a UserControl hosting a Canvas and it is to this canvas that the framework elements are added. The controls are all contained within the boundaries of the canvas and are not overlapping.

Can someone please explain why this border is appearing and how to get rid of it.

Thanks

Comment: Just an idea: red border usually means some kind of validation error, maybe you should check the Validation.Errors attached property, and see if it contains useful information.

Comment: You can use Snoop to check, where the problem is. It helps to inspect the entire Visual Tree. http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for these comments. Although the border does look like one generated by validation errors, I'm not (yet) using any validation at all.